# Zend_Gdata and OAuth

Tags: php, zend-framework, oauth, zend-gdata

I successfully retrieved token key / secret after applying Google Hybrid Protocol (OpenID + OAuth).

Then I'm looking into Zend documentation here:
http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.gdata.html

... and into Calendar API example here:
http://code.google.com/googleapps/marketplace/tutorial_php.html#Integrate-OAuth

They mention about AuthSub method supported by Zend_Gdata library
(especially in Zend_Gdata_HttpClient class form what I can see).

But I cannot figure out how to use my key/secret tokens retrieved by Hybrid method in order to access calendar feeds.

Example mentioned above uses AuthSub authentication, while Google recommends to switch to OAuth if possible and where possible, instead of using AuthSub.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: i will look into it later. but as a fast response i can say: there is a lot of mess in the zend framework, especially when it comes to documentation. a lot of classes also dont work properly in special situations. check out this example for the correct usage of oauth and stuff maby it helps, if not i will look into your specifics later: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837674/google-latitude-returns-empty-location-resource-anything-wrong-in-this-oauth-flo

Comment: A snippet of the code will help...

Answer (score 2):

I think you got half of the solution in calendar + OAuth + php
Here i mention some links that may help you in solving your problem.

Links:
http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/standard/trunk/demos/Zend/Gdata/Calendar.php
http://osdir.com/ml/google-calendar-help-dataapi/2011-06/msg00255.html

Link for contact example:
http://gdatatips.blogspot.com/2008/11/2-legged-oauth-in-php.html